# Python: extract str value from list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list:

list = ['150', '200', '300']

how can I 'extract' the string value? (without getting a list)
If I slice list[0,2] i get a list.

Is list.pop(2) (for 2nd value in the list) the only way to get a string value instead of a list?

Comment: also, `list[0,2]` is not valid

Comment: What's wrong with `lst[2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just index the list at the position which holds the value that you want:

```
>>> lst = ['150', '200', '300']
>>> lst[0] # Remember that indexing is 0-based in Python
'150'
>>> lst[1]
'200'
>>> lst[2]
'300'
>>>
```

Comment: MMM, I should have know that.... thnx